# Is it possible to change the color of a feature in KML when its description is open?

Tags: kml, kmz

I find it particularly hard to navigate a file with several connected LineStrings, which don't have labeling, and when you click one through the left panel, the description popup is quite innacurate in pointing the line, plus it doesn't highlight it or anything.

I'm aware of the mouseover highlight styling, but is there a click/selection styling? Using only kml syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an onclick JavaScript action to KML in the description but you can only change the contents of the HTML via the DOM on any action. However, the changes exist only as long as the description popup is being displayed. When the placemark is selected again the description is re-rendered in HTML as it was originally. Also, you cannot directly change the KML styling (E.g. icon color, etc.) via JavaScript.

Here is a simple JavaScript onClick example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Placemark>
    <name>Hello World</name>
    <snippet>Click the link in the description balloon to run some JavaScript!</snippet>
    <description><![CDATA[
    <html>
      <script>
        function buttonclick() {
          document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'You clicked the button!';
        }
      </script>
      <a href="#" onclick="buttonclick(); return false;">Click me!</a>
      <div id="status" style="font-style: italic; color: #0a0;"></div>
    </html>
    ]]></description>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>-122,37</coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>
</kml>
```

If you want to change the style of a feature when viewed or clicked, etc. then you may want to investigate using [CesiumJS](https://cesiumjs.org/). You can basically add any action to the features.